# I can't install gcc with Mojave 10.14

Tags: xcode, gcc, homebrew

I try to install a fortran compiler on my Mojave system thanks to the command

> brew install gcc

Unfortunately, I have this error message

> The directory that should contain system headers does not exist:
>   /usr/include

I found out that I had to install the latest update of the Command Line Tools, which I did and update Xcode to 10.1 but the error remains the same.

I tried to update brew but it said

> Error: /usr/local must be writable!

and brew doctor said that my version of Xcode is outdated although I just updated to the 10.1 version

So... any help is appreciated.

Thanks everybody

Zhiv

Answer (score 1):

I found very detailed instructions for compiling GCC by "Paul" at https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/05/21/compiling-gcc-macos/

In particular this step will address your problem:

> macOS Mojave changed the location of the system headers, this broke
>   the GCC 8 build process. In order to build GCC install the required
>   header files in the old location:

```
cd /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/
open .
```

Comment: By the way, the inability to modify some directories under /usr, even for root, is related to MacOS System Integrity Protection (SIP).  It's a security measure to prevent hackers from messing with parts of /usr.  But apparently some Apple-blessed packages can still do it.  I'm still able to modify /usr/local (as root) though.